# String concatenation doesn't work with RAISE statement

Tags: postgresql

I have a simple code just to raise an exception:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_0041()
RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE
    msg varchar;
BEGIN
       msg = 'some error msg';
       RAISE 'ERROR: %', msg;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The above code works fine, but the following doesn't:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_0041()
RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE
    msg varchar;
BEGIN
       msg = 'some error msg';
       RAISE 'ERROR: '|| msg;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I would ask why

> RAISE 'ERROR: '|| msg;

doesn't work, it complains about an error around `||`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html) regarding RAISE:

```
RAISE [ level ] 'format' [, expression [, ... ]] [ USING option = 
expression [, ... ] ];
RAISE [ level ] condition_name [ USING option = expression [, ... ] ];
RAISE [ level ] SQLSTATE 'sqlstate' [ USING option = expression [, ... ] ];
RAISE [ level ] USING option = expression [, ... ];
RAISE ;
```

So it does not seem that your second example matches any of available syntax options for RAISE.

As for the first option, the documentation states that:

> After level if any, you can specify a format string (which must be a
> simple string literal, not an expression). The format string specifies
> the error message text to be reported. The format string can be
> followed by optional argument expressions to be inserted into the
> message. Inside the format string, % is replaced by the string
> representation of the next optional argument's value. Write %% to emit
> a literal %. The number of arguments must match the number of %
> placeholders in the format string, or an error is raised during the
> compilation of the function.

Comment: There is an additional relevant sentence in the documentation. Otherwise the first syntax option would fit: "After *level* if any, you can specify a *format* string (which must be a simple string literal, not an expression)."